# JasperPrint jp =JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, con); ..not accepting null in parameters

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have attached the following image of my code.....the red circle at left side is showing the error....i have been working on this error from last 7 days but failed to eradicate....the issue is that the function is not accepting null in the place of parameter.....plz plz plz help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is your [method](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fillReport-java.io.InputStream-java.util.Map-net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource-). You need a map and i guess you are getting NullPointerException but i'm not sure since you posted no stacktrace of error.
 Try using an empty map like this:
`HashMap<String, Object> reportMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, reportMap, con);`

Comment: thanks for the help......But the issue was that i was passing mysqlConnection object instead of Built-in Connection class obj

Comment: Can you make it an answer instead of a comment?